# Should the FAQ page be returned in search results?

Tags: feature-request, site-faq

My first rhetorical question on SO… well I was wondering about the moderation requirements so I made my first trip to meta. I searched for "who can edit questions?", as I had on stackoverflow, and got nothing useful. Then I looked at the "hey, you're new here!" banner and followed the link to the FAQ, where I got the info. (Well, actually I got the idea to directly enter the URL https://stackoverflow.com/faq .)

But if it were my second time visiting meta, I might never have found it.

So, FAQs being frequently asked, wouldn't it be useful to put them somewhere the search engine can find?

**EDIT:** To be crystal clear, here is a link "demonstrating the misbehavior": https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+kind+of+questions+can+I+ask+here%3F

**EDIT 2:** The proposal here is to "put them somewhere the search engine can find." I don't propose rephrasing the FAQ and didn't mean to propose to give it the *format* of a question. So I have edited the title of this question.

Comment: You mean these gems? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq

Comment: No, I mean the pages at stackoverflow.com/faq, meta.stackoverflow.com/faq, etc. That tag is not what I'm looking for, and it has no equivalent on the other sites.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that the FAQ should be consulted *before* searching, since those questions are asked frequently.

You do make a good point, though.

Comment: May be, but I got so used to ignoring the FAQ link that my eyes skipped over it. It shouldn't interfere too much with regular search, being just one page after all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is always this question:

> [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

Joking aside, if you really think that a lot of people search for "who can edit questions?", there's nothing stopping you from asking the question here on meta, so it will eventually be available in the search.

Comment: Although I have a gut feeling it will be closed as a dupe of the above question. But then again, it will still be available in the search and eventually point the asker in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a good idea, it would be interesting if each Q of the FAQ were a separate question actually, tagged SO-FAQ.

Clicking the FAQ link would take you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/so-faq

That said, I don't see this as a *really* good idea, because it just makes the FAQ less usable, AND it allows the masses to rise up against The Double-J Squad with their petty comments (which is what meta is for anyway, huh?)

Comment: Looking back on this page, I think there is a huge misunderstanding here. See update to question.